# Is My betta fish is sick or dying or just old

Tags: health, fish, betta

Ive has a Siamese fighting fish for about a year and about a month ago he started laying on the bottom of the tank.
I have a 20L tank, heater, filter, thermometer, hiding spots plastic plants. 
He used to be very active and only rested at night. He used to eat all the food I put in and then he just stopped, he’s lost colour and he’s not eating.

When this started I thought it would just pass but it didn’t in about a week I started researching. I’ve tried a small piece of pea, he didn’t eat it, I’ve tried two different pellet food and flakes, he didn’t eat them either. After 2 weeks I put 5 black tetras in there thinking he might be lonely, it didn’t change anything I’ve tried blood worms and mosquito larvae, he won’t eat them. 
I’ve checked his water, the ph was high a week ago but it’s alright now, ( at 7.00) the temp is at 26 degrees Celsius. I do 50 % water changes once a week and clean the tank once a month. The nitrites, nitrates and ammonia levels are all good.

I just don’t know what to do, it’s like I’ve tried everything but nothing changes anything, so I don’t know. The tetras are happy and eating. I also have a muscle in there.

Is he just old or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks[image][image]

Comment: Yvette Horsewoman,  it does a little, I might need to add live plants. Thank you

Comment: Let us know how you get on. I hope he's ok